# /usr/bin/crontab execution failed: must be privileged to use -u System error: crontab execution error

Tags: cron, plesk

I want to create a new cronjob via Plesk. After submit the configuration i get the error from my topic.
I have tried chmod and chown to the crontabmng without success.
my crontabmng owner is 
`root:root` and the permission is `-rwxr-xr-x`

Answer (score 1):

Check for suid bit 's' on `/usr/bin/crontab`:

```
# ls -la /usr/bin/crontab
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root 57552 Mar 31  2016 /usr/bin/crontab
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED i think with the following:

```
service psa stopall
chown root.psaadm /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/wrapper
chmod 4110 /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/wrapper
chown root.psaadm /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/mod_wrapper
chmod 4110 /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/mod_wrapper
```

and the last step takes some time

```
service psa start
```

for now its all running and i get no errors.

hope it helps.